# How to work out next most probable letter in a sequence, Natural Language Processing

Tags: nlp

I have the sequence `AGCTTTCGA`and am asked to first list all unigrams and bigrams. As far as I am aware these are correct:

Unigrams:

```
{A, G, C, T, T, T, C, G, A}
```

Bigrams:

```
{AG, GC, CT, TT, TT, TC, CG, GA}
```

Now I need to calculate the next most probable character in this sequence for both the unigram and bigram mode. I know the formula for likelihood is

p(w2|w1) = count(w1, w2) / count(w1)

but am unsure how I would use this here?

Comment: What are you confused about exactly? Did you obtain the counts of each unigram and bigram?

Comment: Sorry, basically this question is asking what does `count(w1, w2)` mean?

Comment: `count(w1, w2)` is the number of times `w2` follows `w1` in your corpus (i.e. the number of occurrences of the bigram `w1w2`). For example, `count("T", "C") = 1`, so p(C | T) = 1 / 3.

Comment: So I think I figured it out, the next likely character in both scenarios is `G` as this is a low corpus meaning not enough examples of characters following from `A` are provided. I guess using the bigrams model the next likely character is nothing as there is no scenario previously given where characters follow on from `GA`

Comment: In the bigram scenario, the most likely character after `A` is `G` indeed: P(G|A) = 1 because the only occurrence of A is followed by G. However, this is not the case in the unigram scenario. In a unigram model, the probability of the next character does not depend on the previous character(s): the most likely character will be T because it is the most frequent p(T) = 3/9 > 2/9 = p(A) = p(G) = p(C).

Comment: Ohhhh... I actually get it now. That makes a lots of sense, thanks! If you want to amalgamate your comments to make an answer I'll make the question answered.